# How do I stop IIS from executing cached ASP.NET classes that have been updated or deleted?

Tags: asp.net, iis

After updating some ashx files and related dlls, my server is still executing the old versions.  It continues to execute them even if I remove all of the files from the server.

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**

After 10-15 minutes the server reloads the application.  That is a livable situation for a production server, but for development, it makes it very hard to get things done.

I have not been able to fix the server, but I came up with a hackish workaround.  I created a page that calls `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()`.  I just need to load that page when I push files to my development server.

Comment: Are the assemblies registered in the GAC?

Comment: @James Johnson, not unless that happens automatically.  I just copy my assemblies to the bin folder.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer? That tends to be the most common issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the temporary ASP.NET folder contents.

Comment: What temporary folder? I only have access to the contents of the web site.

Comment: Hmm. You don't actually have access to IIS or the server? The ASP.NET temp folder is usually located at: C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: No, I don't have access, I can get temporary access to configure the server, but it takes several days.  Since asking my question, the cache has cleared, but I can't wait a 1/2 hour every time this happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know if there's much you can do without access to the server. If it's any consolation, it sounds like a server issue. You might try using dynamic compilation, but I'm not sure whether that requires any interaction with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Even in shared hosting you should be able to restart the app pools of your website. Can you try this?

If you cannot do this try this other trick: change the Url adding an unused parameters, i.e. ?foo=1 (I normally used this trick for other reasons but might also work in this context).

Comment: I can not restart the app pool.  Changing the query string prevents the browser from caching documents, this is a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Web.config file (any change, doesn't matter what).  This will force the ASP.NET app to reload.

Changing the dll's in bin should have done this too, but it's worth trying to also change the Web.config file.

Comment: No luck, at the moment I am waiting for changes to web.config to reload.